# Install Jupyter Notebook extensions on copy hosted on cloned Github Repository?

Tags: github, jupyter, hosted, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I have a cloned Jupyter Notebook hosted on Github. Locally, I have installed Jupyter Notebook extensions but these are not maintained within the Github environment.

Is there a way to install the extensions on the Github server so that cells can be toggled on/off with notebook extensions? Or will I have to go with a Javascript hack as per https://gist.github.com/Zsailer/5d1f4e357c78409dd9a5a4e5c61be552?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this cant' be done as per below:

When you add Jupyter Notebook or IPython Notebook files with a .ipynb extension on GitHub, they will render as static HTML files in your repository.

The interactive features of the notebook, such as custom JavaScript plots, will not work in your repository on GitHub. For an example, see Linking and Interactions.ipynb.

To view your Jupyter notebook with JavaScript content rendered or to share your notebook files with others you can use nbviewer. For an example, see Linking and Interactions.ipynb rendered on nbviewer.

- from: https://help.github.com/en/articles/working-with-jupyter-notebook-files-on-github